# Why use a property for the app delegate?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm auditing some code that has an `appDelegate` property in many of the view controllers.

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) TheAppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

Leaving aside the design implications of such coupling, is there any *benefit*, other than convenience, of an `appDelegate` property versus retrieving the app delegate:

```
TheAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TheAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDelegate someMethod];
```

Comment: This is all extremely subjective, so I'll give you my opinion: Use of the AppDelegate in any class or function that does not bridge the system and the application is a code smell.  Having a property reference to it is doubly so.  I feel the ugly way of getting it is a discouragement in itself (much like the various casting methods in C++).  There is no benefit in either case (one forces you to remember to set or define a property, the other forces verbosity).

Comment: @CodaFi, is there a way I could narrow the question so it's not *extremely subjective*? I'm mainly curious in reasons why I a property is better if I *must* use such code.

Comment: It's subjective in that it's a coding-style question, rather than one about concrete figures.  The only answers you could possibly receive are opinions and experiences.  I can give you a million cases where I've personally used one or the other in some corner-case, but it would never amount to an answer that was authoritative.

Comment: @CodaFi, I intended to narrow the question to be helpful. However, if after a few responses I indeed receive opinions, I'll delete my question.

Comment: I'm going to vote for 'a little subjective'.  I can see at least one clear benefit.

Answer (score 3):

I also sometimes do this, ie. declare a property for a dependency that can be fetched using a singleton access method:

```
@class Foo : NSObject
@property(strong) NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter;
@end

@implementation Foo

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    [self setNotificationCenter:[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]];
    return self;
}

@end
```

The advantage is that you get looser coupling on the dependency. You can easily supply your own mocked instance, for example. In some cases it also makes the code shorter, writing `_notificationCenter` instead of `[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]`.

And a third reason that I can think of is that declaring the property makes the dependency explicit: you know by looking at the public API that the state or behaviour of the object depends on the app delegate. Using a singleton in the class implementation completely hides this fact.

But if there are many controllers in your app that depend on the app delegate, it’s probably just a design deficiency.

Comment: Makes sense for a general property. But when would I mock the `appDelegate`?

Comment: Maybe to test some notifications posted by the app delegate? Just guessing. Anyway, it’s quite possible that in your app the property really does not make sense.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: One obvious answer would be unit testing your class's interactions with the app delegate (e.g. it sends certain messages to the delegate at certain times).

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question as framed.

The specific benefits are :-

Cleaner code - The property is set once ( and could be read only).
If you use it more than once

self.appDelegate is simpler than fetching the appDelegate from the shared application every time. ( and simpler is better)

There might be a minor efficiency advantage ( although this is definitely premature optimisation and might not exist depending on the compiler).

I have to agree with CodaFi that it is a bit smelly, so there is the middle ground of creating some syntactic sugar to hide some complexity.

```
@class MyAppDelegate;
@interface MySharedAppDelegate : NSObject 

+ (MyAppDelegate*) appDelegate;
@end

#include "MyAppDelegate.h"
@implementation MySharedAppDelegate

+ ( MyAppDelegate*) appDelegate {
    return (MyAppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].appDelegate;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use a macro rather than defining a property in every viewcontrollers
like

```
#define appDelegate ((MYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate])
```

define this in constants.h and including the header in the .pch file, i can have this `appDelegate`  in any class in my code.

Comment: Don't know about having *`appDelegate` everywhere in my code*, but nice alternative.

Comment: just meant that in any classes in the project :)

Answer (score 1):

I like doing this:

```
//in .pch file
#import "Includes.h"

//in Includes.h
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#define APPDELEGATE() (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]
```

Then anywhere I need to ask the appDelegate something I just say

```
[APPDELEGATE() someMethod];
```

Having a property for AppDelegate somewhere else seems like a bad idea. Can't say why, other than already having an easy way of getting that reference (sharedApplication).

In this case it's probably just for convenience for the developer. I have to say though, that "needing" a reference to AppDelegate everywhere is probably more of an indicator of spaghetti code and bad encapsulation.

*By the way, I store references to some "global" variables inside the appDelegate, which may also be an indicator of bad encapsulation...which is why I use the APPDELEGATE() declaration in the first place ;-)

**Things like NSDateFormatter that you'll need quite often but doesn't necessarily "live" inside a class, (you don't need one for every instance but can be applied to several instances), or reference to some particular state, like "global application font size"

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is subjective at all.  The question is:

> is there any benefit, other than convenience, of an appDelegate
>   property versus retrieving the app delegate

And I think the answer is "no". There's no benefit, other than convenience.

Ideally, you have no (or minimal) coupling between your app delegate and your view controllers, so which method you use shouldn't much matter. In the project I'm working on right now, I'm just retrieving the delegate when I need it (which is only 2 places in the whole codebase). If you were doing this in dozens of places, maybe it'd make more sense to have it as a property, but again, it's purely for convenience.